# urllib not taking context as a parameter

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to add the sssl.SSlContext to a urlopen method but keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

I'm using python 3 and urllib. This has a context parameter defined - https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html. So I don't understand why it is throwing the error. But either way this is the code:

```
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
request = Request(url, content, headers)
request.get_method = lambda: method

if sys.version_info[0] == 2 and sys.version_info[1] < 8:
    result = urlopen(request)
else:
    gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    result = urlopen(request, context=gcontext)
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`urllib.request.urlopen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

> Changed in version 3.4.3: context was added.

the parameter `context` will be added in Python 3.4.3. You need to fall back for lower version.

---

In Python 2.x, it's added in Python 2.7.9. ([`urllib.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen), [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen))

Comment: it is said that [`3.4.3 final: February 22, 2015`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/#id2) i.e., it is not released yet.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I missed that it is not released yet. Thank you for comment.

Comment: So is there a workaround or can I simply not use the SSLContext?

Comment: @Danrex, Change the predicate: `if (sys.version_info[0] == 2 and sys.version_info < (2,7,9)) or sys.version_info < (3,4,3)`

Comment: @Danrex, Or, try with `context=..` argument, then catch `TypeError`: retry with no `context=...` argument.

Comment: @Danrex: you can [customize ssl support since Python 2.4](https://gist.github.com/zed/1347055)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the wrong docs. https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html are the ones you want. You were using Python 2.X documentation.

Comment: aaahhh so I was. Still can I make this work at all or am I going to have to use the older Python version?